# asp.net Json with asmx not working on server It is working just in local?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asmx

I am trying to write webservices Json in asp.net. This code is working on my local pc. But it is not working on server.

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void GetMember() {       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DALMember.GetAll()));
  }

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DOAdverisingModule.AdsModule.context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e) +295
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +71

Comment: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  Step through and figure out which one is null.

Comment: how can I do it ? there is no problem on local

Comment: Well, it is probably `DALMember` since the line above the error refers to `DALMember.GetAll()`.  So for whatever reason that object is null so the `.GetAll` call throws.

Comment: As far as why it is working locally and not on the server, are they using the same data source?

Comment: sql server is connected for both side local and server.

Comment: Is it the same basic request?  Same information, same logical path through the code?  Something must be different for it to work one way and not the other.

Comment: yeap all they are same. I write try catch it gives me same error

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend switch to MVC API.  Web services are old news, and MVC API will allow you a broader spectrum of usability.

Second, the error that you are getting, is it when you are stepping through the code of the (.ASMX)? -- meaning, can you execute code on your site that calls the web service no problem, its just whatever code you are trying to execute within the web service is failing?

Comment: When ı clicked the GetMember() and invoke  it gives me this error. But on local it is working fine. I am gonna lose my mind

Comment: Is DALMember.GetAll() method available to this page?  You may need to instantiate DALMember first,     DALMember dm = new DALMember()

Comment: DALMember.GetAll() returns a list of member

Comment: and you have a reference to using Newtonsoft.Json;?

Comment: try DALMember m = new DALMember();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m.GetAll()));

Comment: yeap but I realized now when I using HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("something") it gives error again I thing the problem from this line